# How are integer literals stored?

Tags: c#, integer, literals

Does a small integer literal in C# (e.g.`12`) uses 4 bytes of stack like an integer variable‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌? Does it need 4 bytes?

Comment: A literal is not (never) placed on the stack.

Comment: So where are they stored?

Comment: A literal is only placed on the stack if it is in the parameter list to a method.  A literal is added to the assembly language compiler code which is not part of the execution stack.

Comment: @jdweng So if it is not on the stack, will it use 4 bytes? it will be just a string. right?

Comment: It will use a register. Typically registers are available in both the full-width and half-width of the data bus. Your *short* literal will occupy 2 bytes of IL, and either likely 2 bytes or 4 bytes (or even 8 bytes on an x64) of NGEN'ed code; then will be moved into a register before being operated upon.

Comment: It depends on the context. When a literal is used in an expression or assignment it is converted to a 'value' first. What exactly happens then is up to the optimizer and cannot be gleaned from the language specification. But usually an integer literal will be stored and processed as 32 bits.

Comment: My answer was incorrect so I deleted it from the thread.

Comment: Why exactly do you ask this? Do you think it will matter in any way?  The answer might be different on the micro .NET framework. The point is that you shouldn't notice.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: If integer literals use less memory, I think I should prefer using them wherever possible. Also it is interesting for me to know if there a deference between the storage of an integer variable and a literal integer specially in number of bytes they use.

Comment: What alternatives do you think you have? This is a non-question.

Comment: The literal becomes part of the executable which is not on the stack.  So if you have in your code b = a + 4.  The assembler may use the AX register to store both a and b.  So the assembly instruction would be AX + 4.  The 4 is an immediate in the assembly language code.

Comment: @jdweng So can we say that it is just like string in executable file not a like a variable in stack?

Comment: Correct, except if you pass a constant to a method in a parameter list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a short integer literal in C# ...

You cannot declare a literal of type *short* so the question is iffy.  In practice, the C# compiler will treat it like an *int* (or *long* if large enough) and readily convert it to *byte* or *short* where appropriate without a cast.  And complain when such a conversion causes an overflow.

It will end up getting encoded in a processor instruction like MOV or PUSH, depending on how you use the literal.  A practical example, use the Debug > Windows > Disasssembly window to see it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(12);
    }
```

Generates:

```
  005B2DB0 B9 0C 00 00 00       mov         ecx,0Ch  
  005B2DB5 E8 7E 38 BE 72       call        73196638  
  005B2DBA C3                   ret
```

Note the MOV instruction and the instruction bytes it generates.  B9 is the "move 32-bit immediate" instruction, the next 4 bytes are the value in little-endian order.  Otherwise selected because the C# compiler used the WriteLine(Int32) overload, it does not have overloads for *byte* or *short*.  Use the same technique to see what happens with your specific code.

Comment: sorry by short I meant small. not the `short ` integer type. I meant when it is short why should it use 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a `short` numeric literal. You can only declare numeric literals of types `int`, `float`(`f`suffix), `double`(`d`suffix), `uint`(`u`suffix), `long`(`l`suffix), `ulong`(`ul`suffix) and `decimal`(`m`suffix).

All numeric literals without suffixes e.g. `12` are inferred to be of the first of these types in which their value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`. so ***if*** `12` were put on the stack, it would require 4 bytes on a 32-bit system.

Comment: Your second statement is not entirely true: "If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int,uint, long, ulong", source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx, so it won't always be inferred to be of type int, that is just the most common case.

Comment: How if it is not put on stack? will it need 4 bytes?

Comment: When the CLR needs the parameter, then 4 bytes is placed on the stack. Consider the msil instruction `ldc.i4` (eg. `ldc.i4 255`). It is baked in the .dll when compiled. So it only uses memory space when you actually execute the instruction. Otherwise its just located on-disk (as an instruction, and as a copy of the dll in-memory eventually).

Comment: @MinimusHeximus, if not put on the stack, it would just be compiled IL code, it would never require memory allocation.

Comment: @Caramiriel, I'm guessing you did not notice the big bold italic "if"?

Comment: @SaebAmini, No I just wanted to provide additional information. Once I knew everything from C# was compiled to msil, it helped me a lot to understand whats actually going on. Maybe it helps other people as well :)

Comment: @Caramiriel, oh ok, I received a downvote simultaneously with your comment and thought it was you; appreciate the extra info :)